# How do I add a server side route that can call Meteor code?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am trying to allow users to upload images to a site I have built with Meteor, which requires a server-side route I can POST data to. Is there a way to set up a route server side such that I can call Meteor code from it (for example, a route that I can call this.userId or Meteor.userId() from)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Server side routing is on the roadmap](https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae), but not yet available the way you need it. (At that link, Server-side rendering is set for version 1.0).

In the interim, you can do *some* server side rendering with Tom Coleman's excellent [meteor-router mrt package](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router#server-side-routing). It's unclear to me how much of this will make it into Meteor core.

More likely, however, for the file upload problem, this [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/222) describes the problem, and it looks like people have had luck implementing [imgur's xhr api](http://api.imgur.com/examples#uploading_js) or perhaps even better is [this smart idea](https://gist.github.com/3922137).

Hope this helps.